# PayPal through Childbrowser on PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, paypal-sandbox

I'm developing a PhoneGap application that I need to connect with PayPal. I was reading about different PayPal plugins for iOS and Android for PhoneGap, but I want to do it with the childbrowser because I need it to work on BlackBerry too. I need some help because I have never done this before.

Thanks
Im trying with this!!

```
function openPaypal()
                    {
                        alert("paypal");
                         openBrowser("https://sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr");
                    }
                </script> 
                <form  name="formulario" id="formulario" action="" method="post">
                <!-- Identificar tu tienda (recuerda los datos puestos en la cuente creada como seller en developer.paypal.com) -->
                <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="Tienda de Prueba"><!-- el nombre da igual -->
                <input type="hidden" name="business" value="fjvb1@alu.ua.es"><!-- introducir el email de la cuenta de prueba -->
                <!-- Especificar el tipo de boton/formulario en paypal -->
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick"> 
                <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
                <!-- Ponemos que no pregunten sobre el envio -nuestra web se hace cargo- -->
                <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
                <!-- El unico item es la compra realizada -nosotros con el id de la compra ya sacamos los producto- -->
                <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Compra desde Tienda de Prueba">
                <!-- Especificamos el id del pedido -->
                <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">
                <!-- Ponemos el total de la compra -->
                <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="30">
                <!-- Especificamos pago en euro -->
                <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
                <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
                <!-- Como dato extra, enviamos el codigo del cliente -->
                <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="1">
                <!-- Pagina de vuelta de la compra efectuada -->
                <input type="hidden" name="return" value="">
                <!-- Pagina de vuelta de la compra con error-->
                <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="">


            </div>
            <div class="submit">
                    <a href="#"  onClick="openPaypal();" class="enquiry"><img src="../images/confirmbutton-passive.png" id="button1" style="width:100%; margin: 0px auto;"/></a>
                    </form>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you create a simple page on a server that your application opens up on all platforms and just have a PayPal form on that page?

Comment: Yes I have a server, but Im dont know what I have to do? If someone can say me a example?

Comment: Just create a simple PayPal form page the will be hosted on your server, then in your PhoneGap application have the Childbrowser open to that page.

Comment: do you have some code example?

Comment: Please, I need help with this!!

Comment: What code example? How to use the [PayPal API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/)? How to make a [form](http://webdesign.about.com/od/forms/qt/make-html-forms-work.htm)? Using an [InAppBrowser](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser)?

Comment: Hot to make a form to send to sandbox paypal... I try with one form, is loaded paypal sandbox well, but I cant change the value inputs to send my special information for example, dinamic price or dinamic description!!

Comment: Take a look at the PayPal API documentation then. It might be something do to with that.